# In Shangri La missions, what are the seekers locations, and what's the point of finding them?

Tags: far-cry-4

I noticed it was possible to interact with "seekers" in Shangri La levels.  As far as I know (I haven't completed all Shangri La missions yet), seekers are dead people with which you can interact and learn more about Shangri La's lore.

Is there more than lore to uncover ?  Does it reward anything to find them all ?
Where are they ?  I couldn't find one in the "The Hunt For Rakshasa" mission, for instance.

Comment: Yes Very hard to find might be this video will help :: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdOxXp5-cg8

Answer (score 4):

When you start a Shangri La mission you have three health bars. Each seeker you find will give you an additional health bar for that mission.

Tested on Xbox One version.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a walkthrough for all five Shangri-La missions:

- [Mission 1: The Protector’s Arrival](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kH8tfB6yug)
- [Mission 2: The Hunt for Rakshasa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxn98QfSAMQ)
- [Mission 3: The Surrender to Paradise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xs467Q_5yIE)
- [Mission 4: The Paradise Destroyed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzpsUkzytok)
- [Mission 5: The Unpainted Future](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coU8UMV2XVU)